# jQuery plugin grunt build change webservice urls

Tags: jquery, plugins, build, gruntjs

Quick question,

I have a jquery plugin using Grunt, now in my js file I have a webservice listed i.e.

```
//webservice settings
api_endpoint: "http://localhost/api/v1"
```

And this is fine in my dev, but when i got prod I want this changed to i.e.

```
api_endpoint: "http://prod/api/v1"
```

My Grunt file looks something like this

```
    // Concat definitions
    concat: {
        options: {
            banner: "<%= meta.banner %>"
        },
        dist: {
            src: ["src/jquery.myPlugin.autocomplete.js", "src/jquery.myPlugin.tabs.js", "src/jquery.myPlugin.clearsearch.js", "src/jquery.myPlugin.v2.0.js"],
            dest: "dist/jquery.myPlugin.v2.0.js"
        }
    },

    // Lint definitions
    jshint: {
        files: ["src/jquery.myPlugin.v2.0.js"],
        options: {
            jshintrc: ".jshintrc"
        }
    },

    // Minify definitions
    uglify: {
        my_target: {
            src: ["dist/jquery.myPlugin.v2.0.js"],
            dest: "dist/jquery.myPlugin.v2.0.min.js"
        },
        options: {
            banner: "<%= meta.banner %>"
        }
    },

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-variablize');
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-concat");
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-jshint");
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-uglify");
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-sass");
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

grunt.registerTask("build", [
    "clean:pre",
    "concat",
    "uglify",
    "cssmin",
    "copy",
    'clean:post',
    "watch"
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [grunt-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-replace).

Set config

```
replace: {
    api: {
        options: {
            patterns: [
                {
                    match: '/http://localhost/api/v1/g',
                    replacement: 'http://prod/api/v1'
                }
            ]
        },
        files: [
            {
                expand: true, 
                flatten: true, 
                src: ['dist/jquery.myPlugin.v2.0.js'], 
                dest: 'dist/'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Load package

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-replace');
```

Add distribution task

```
// This could be done better, but just example
grunt.registerTask("dist", [
    "clean:pre",
    "concat",
    "replace:api",
    "uglify",
    "cssmin",
    "copy",
    'clean:post',
    "watch"
]);
```

And run task

```
grunt dist
```

Comment: getting an error unable to replace string without @@

Comment: Sorry. It had to be regexp pattern. You could also replace endpoint url with `@@API_ENDPOINT` and replace `match` would be `API_ENDPOINT`. But this means you have to replace it in `build` task too.